# Simple Lighttpd Rewrite Rule not working

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I have the following URL

http://www.website.com/pub/?code=USERINPUT

I would like it to appear as

http://www.website.com/pub/code/USERINPUT

I set up the following in my lighttpd.conf and I just get 404'ed every time!

```
url.rewrite = ( "^/code/(.*)$" => "/pub/index.php?code=$1" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing it to

```
url.rewrite = ( "^/pub/code/(.*)$" => "/pub/index.php?code=$1" )
```